# NodeJs Cheerio results: Array of Arrays to JSON object using lodash?

Tags: node.js, arrays, express, lodash, cheerio

I'm trying to get some information from a site and I would like to format it better into an object of keys and values. I'm using [nightmare](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nightmare) and [cheerio-tableparser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio-tableparser) to parse a complex table...Currently the data is in an Array of arrays and I would like to map the the key value pairs. The first array `array[0]` and the second array `array[2]` are the keys, and `array[1]` and `array[3]` are the values... is there an easy way to make this association with lodash? The array is 16 arrays long but all follow the same relationship. However, i would like to **ignore** `if a key is null and a value is null`.

So, the relationship is:

```
{
  "array[0][0]" : "array[1][0]",
  "array[0][1]" : "array[1][1]"
...
}
```

Maps to:

```
{
  "Serial Number" : "627",
  "Manufacturer Name" : "DEHAVILLAND"
 ...
}
```

Array

```
[
    [
        "Serial Number",
        "Manufacturer Name",
        "Model",
        "Type Aircraft",
        "Pending Number Change",
        "Date Change Authorized",
        "MFR Year",
        "Type Registration",
        "Name",
        "Street",
        "City",
        "County",
        "Country",
        "Type Certificate Data Sheet",
        "Engine Manufacturer",
        "Engine Model",
        "A/W Date",
        "The information contained in this record should be the most current Airworthiness information available in the historical aircraft record. However, this data alone does not provide the basis\n                                    for a determination regarding the airworthiness of an aircraft or the current aircraft configuration. For specific information, you may request a copy of the aircraft record at\n                                    http://aircraft.faa.gov/e.gov/ND/",
        "None",
        "Certificate Number",
        "None",
        "None"
    ],
    [
        "627",
        "DEHAVILLAND",
        "DHC-2 MK. I(L20A)",
        "Fixed Wing Single-Engine",
        "None",
        "None",
        "1953",
        "Corporation",
        "WARD AIR INC",
        "8991 YANDUKIN DR",
        "JUNEAU",
        "JUNEAU DIV",
        "UNITED STATES",
        "None",
        "NONE",
        "NONE",
        "12/10/1976",
        "The information contained in this record should be the most current Airworthiness information available in the historical aircraft record. However, this data alone does not provide the basis\n                                    for a determination regarding the airworthiness of an aircraft or the current aircraft configuration. For specific information, you may request a copy of the aircraft record at\n                                    http://aircraft.faa.gov/e.gov/ND/",
        "None",
        "T061436",
        "None",
        "None"
    ],
    [
        "Status",
        "Certificate Issue Date",
        "Expiration Date",
        "Type Engine",
        "Dealer",
        "Mode S Code (base 8 / Oct)",
        "Mode S Code (Base 16 / Hex)",
        "Fractional Owner",
        "WARD AIR INC",
        "8991 YANDUKIN DR",
        "State",
        "Zip Code",
        "UNITED STATES",
        "Type Certificate Holder",
        "Classification",
        "Category",
        "Exception Code",
        "The information contained in this record should be the most current Airworthiness information available in the historical aircraft record. However, this data alone does not provide the basis\n                                    for a determination regarding the airworthiness of an aircraft or the current aircraft configuration. For specific information, you may request a copy of the aircraft record at\n                                    http://aircraft.faa.gov/e.gov/ND/",
        "None",
        "Issue Date",
        "None",
        "None"
    ],
    [
        "Valid",
        "02/24/2006",
        "07/31/2022",
        "Reciprocating",
        "No",
        "52022212",
        "A8248A",
        "NO",
        "WARD AIR INC",
        "8991 YANDUKIN DR",
        "ALASKA",
        "99801-8086",
        "UNITED STATES",
        "None",
        "Standard",
        "Normal",
        "No",
        "The information contained in this record should be the most current Airworthiness information available in the historical aircraft record. However, this data alone does not provide the basis\n                                    for a determination regarding the airworthiness of an aircraft or the current aircraft configuration. For specific information, you may request a copy of the aircraft record at\n                                    http://aircraft.faa.gov/e.gov/ND/",
        "None",
        "02/24/2006",
        "None",
        "None"
    ]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution:

```
let reg1 = _.zipObject(tables[0], tables[1]);
let reg2 = _.zipObject(tables[2], tables[3]);
    return {...reg1, ...reg2}
```